# Getting data of Nested Json from python in javascript

Tags: javascript, python-2.7

I have nested json as shown below

```
 {
    'id': '4SE-16',
    'name': 'Min Khant Lu',
    "roll_call": [
        {
            "subj1": 76,
            "subj2": 78,
            "subj3": 80,
            "subj4": 90,
            "subj5": 91,
            "subj6": 95,
            "subj7": 95,
        }
    ],
    "subj_id": 7
}
```

I passed these data from python using 'render_template'
Getting data of id, and name is ok.
But how can u get the data for each subject.

Comment: what are you trying to do you serialize as a dictionary already use a for loop or something I dunno get data make it more concrete

Answer (score 2):

```
console.log(myObject.roll_call[0]["subj1"])
```

will print 76 on the developers tools console (hit F12)